# Change the library in GDB

Tags: linux, gdb

I am debugging using GDB in linux but while debugging it's loading symbol from some library.

How can I tell GDB to load symbols from my library instead?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell GDB to load symbols from my library instead?

The need for this usually arises when you have a copy of shared library built with debug info, and a stripped copy of the that library installed on the system. The solution is to use `add-symbol-file` command.

However, it is *very* likely that you are not in the above situation, and that what you are *really* asking for is "how can I make the program (and not just GDB) use my copy of the library instead of system-installed one?"

If so, the answer is to either rebuild your executable with `-Wl,-rpath=/my/lib` (where `/my/lib` contains `libfoo.so`), or to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/lib`.  This will cause your program use `/my/lib/libfoo.so` at runtime, and GDB will load symbols from it automagically.